# Evaluating an integral across contours: $\int_C\text{Re}\;z\,dz\,\text{ from }-4\text{ to } 4$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

This is for an assignment, describing the procedure is most beneficial for me, rather that solely computing the result.

---

I want to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_C\text{Re}\;z\,dz\,\text{  from }-4\text{ to } 4$$
Along the line segments from $-4$ to $-4-4i$ to $4-4i$ to $4$, e.g:

[image: Bad drawing of the path described above]

---

So I want to evaluate three integrals of the above three paths, and add them together, is this correct?

---

Parametrisation for each curve respectively:
\begin{align}
z(t)=-4-4it,\quad &0\leq t \leq 1\\
z(t)=-4-4i+8t,\quad &0\leq t \leq 1\\
z(t)=4-4i+4it,\quad &0\leq t \leq 1
\end{align}

---

$$\int_0^1 (-4-4it)(-4i)dt + \int_0^1 (-4-4i+8t)(8)dt+\int_0^1 (4-4i+4it)(4i)dt$$
$$=16\int_0^1 (i-t)dt+32\int_0^1(-1-i+2t)dt+16\int_0^1 (i+1-4t)dt$$
$$=16\left[it-\frac{t^2}{2}\right]_0^1 + 32\left[-t-it+t^2\right]_0^1+16\left[it+t-2t^2\right]_0^1$$
$$=16(i-\frac12)+32(-1-i+1)+16(i+1-2)$$
$$16i-8-32-32i+32+16i+16-32$$
$$=-24$$

Comment: Yes. Your next step is to parametrize the line segments.

Comment: Well you probably don't want to substitute $x$ just yet in the last equation, but you have the right idea. On the left vertical leg, $\operatorname{Re}z$ is constant and $dz = i\,dy$, similarly for the other legs.

Comment: @SkiesBurn Please let me know how I can improve my answer.   I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Correct, but the notation $$\int_\alpha^\beta x\,dz$$ is not advisable, because you need to emphasize that we are talking about a **straight line** from $\alpha$ to $\beta$.  If we took a different route from $\alpha$ to $\beta$, the result might be different.

Comment: On the first path, $\operatorname{Re}{z}=-4$, $dz = i dy$.  On the second, $\operatorname{Re}{z}=x$, $dz =dx$.  On the third, $\operatorname{Re}{z}=4$, $dz = i dy$.

Comment: @Ron I got $32i$, can you verify?

Comment: @SkiesBurn: yup.

Comment: @RonGordon Sorry I don't mean to be annoying, but I just want to clarify that the yup was referring to me being correct, and not saying yes to the fact that you can verify

Comment: @SkiesBurn: Yes.  Definitely.  Of course.  Affirmative.  Oui.  Ja.

Comment: @RonGordon lol - what I meant was that the question 'can you verify?' was answered with 'yes', so I didn't know if that was a, 'yes you are correct' or if it was 'yes I can verify', thanks though, I assume the second one does mean yes I am correct - although this time you answered yes to a two option thing again, so I still can't know for sure

Comment: You were correct.  I verified.

Comment: @RonGordon Yay! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_C xdz = \int_0^{-4} (-4) \,i\,dy+\int_{-4}^{4}x\,dx+\int_{-4}^0 (4) \,i\,dy=i32$$

Comment: So I can write $z=-4-4xi, 0\leq x \leq 1$ for the parametrisation of the first curve.

$z=-4i-12+8x, 1\leq x \leq 2$ etc. Are those strange symbols for $y=\pm4$ actually $\pm $ signs?

Comment: Yes  that is the starting point.

Comment: What's wrong with my attempt?

Comment: How on earth is there a real part in the answer?  The integral over $x$ should be zero.  The nonzero pieces of the integral are imaginary.

Comment: @RonGordon So how do I do it right? Why is my attempt above all real?

Comment: @rongordon Yes. Thanks for the catch.  Corrected