# Evaluate $ \int_c x dz $ from $-4$ to $4$ along countour along contour polygon from $(-4,0),(-4,4)(4,4),(4,0))$

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $ \int_c x dz $ from $-4$ to $4$ along countour

[image: countour polygon]

*It will take me a few hours to draw(type ) on latex*

---

**got the answer that its 0 but it had diff solution of back of book**

First find parameterizations for diagram. The general equation for line of two complex points is 
$$z(t)=z_1+(z_2-z_1)t  \hspace{ .5cm} t\in[0,1] $$
For $C_1$ $z_1=-4,x_2=-4+4i $ $t\in[0,1]$
$$\begin{aligned}
z_1(t)&= z_1+(z_2-z_1)t
\\    &=-4+(4i)t
\\    &=-4+4it
\end{aligned}$$

For $C_2$ $z_1=-4+4i$,$z_2=4+4i$
$$\begin{aligned}
z_1(t)&= z_1+(z_2-z_1)t
\\    &=(-4+4i)+((4+4i)-(-4+4i))t
\\    &=-4+4i+8t
\\    &=(-4+8t)+4i
\end{aligned}$$

For $C_3$ $z_1=4+4i$ and $z_2=4$
$$\begin{aligned}
z_1(t)&= z_1+(z_2-z_1)t
\\    &=(4+4i)+((4)-(4+4i))t
\\    &=4+i(4+4t)
\\    &=4+i4(1+t)
\\    &=4+4i+4it
\end{aligned}$$

Trying to integrate $$ \int_c x dz = \int_{c_{1}} x dz+ \int_{c_{2}} x dz+\int_{c_{3}} x dz$$
Using $\int_c f(z)dz=\int^a_b f(z(t))z'(t)dt $
$$\begin{aligned}
   \int_{c_{1}}  x dz     &= \int^1_0 (-4 *i)dt
\\ \int_{c_{2}}  x dz     &=  \int^1_0 (4+8t)8dt
\\ \int_{c_{3}} x  dz     &=  \int^1_0 (4)(4i)dt
\end{aligned} $$
so   $$ \begin{aligned}
 \int_c x dz &= \int_{c_{1}} x dz+ \int_{c_{2}} x dz+\int_{c_{3}} x dz
             = \int_{c_{2}} x dz
             =\int^1_0 (4+8t)8dt
             =8[-4t+8/2 t^2]^1_0
             =0
 \end{aligned}$$

s**o $\int_c f(z)dz=0$ but the answer back of book is $-32i$ something is off** If i had to guess what I am doing wrong is not seeing what is $f(z(t))$ which i think should be x(t) if $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272423/evaluating-an-integral-across-contours-int-c-textre-z-dz-text-from-4?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral over $C_1$ is missing $x(t) = 4$ and thus should be $\int_{0}^1 4 \cdot (-4i) \text{d}t$.
Your last integral is in the wrong direction, as $z_1 = 4+4i - 4it$.
So instead of $\int_{C_1} x \text{d}z = - \int_{C_3} x \text{d}z$, you need to integrate both integrals, and add the outcomes to the result, which gives $-32 i$.